# Azure Function to blob storage, specify filename and metadata

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

This question is fairly straightforward. I haven't figured if it's possible to specify the filename programmatically and adding metadata to the output blob object as described in a binding in an Azure Function built on NodeJS. Is it possible and how would one do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want an output binding?

Comment: Yes, through an output to blob storage binding specify programmatically the filename and some metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently support imperative specification of the output blob path in Node.js functions. If you need that level of control you'll have to use the Azure Storage SDK yourself to create blobs, rather than using our declarative output bindings.

We have a tracking item [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/85) for adding dynamic binding support, which would enable your scenario.

We do support binding expressions for blob output paths that allow you to specify paths based on random guids (e.g. `{sys.randGuid}`) or timestamp (e.g. `{sys.utcNow:mm-dd-yyyy}`) using custom format expressions. But that only goes so far.

Comment: Hi @mathewc and what about appending to blob? Is this supported for js?